# Why doesn't positions of the list that's added in the loop get the same style?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to add <li> in the loop, taking the elements from the array. The list has to be shown as one horizontal line, so I created a class in CSS file. The style works, but only on elements that's being added outside the loop, but not inside, which is very strange to me. The content of page "index.html" is formed by JS file. So the function in JS is...

```
function MainPage(){

    document.querySelector('title').innerText = "Main";
    document.querySelector('header').innerHTML=
        `<h1 style="color:rgb(50, 35, 117);"><p align="center">Music Albums</p></h1>
        <hr>
        <ul class = "menu">
            <li><a onclick="MainPage()">Main</a></li>`;
    countries.forEach(
        (country) =>{
            document.querySelector('header').innerHTML +=
                `<li><a onclick="CategoryPage('${country.id}')">${country.name}</a></li>`;
        }
    );

    document.querySelector('header').innerHTML += `</ul>`;
   
}
```

I showed only that part of the function that's about the problem - the menu that's shown in <header> section.

<li>Main</li> is in the horizontal menu, while others is listed as vertical list below... The information about other <li> is taken from an array "countries" that exists outside the function.

Comment: It's not clear to me what problem you're trying to describe.  Can you update this to a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: You should build the HTML for the whole `<ul>` block as a **string**, and only when it's complete add it to the header. When you add the content bit by bit, you can't rely on the browser to interpret what you're doing the way you expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

Build the `<ul>` as a single string. When that's complete, append it to the header.

```
function MainPage(){

    document.querySelector('title').innerText = "Main";
    const header = document.querySelector('header');
    header.innerHTML=
        `<h1 style="color:rgb(50, 35, 117);"><p align="center">Music Albums</p></h1>
        <hr>`;

    let list = `<ul class = "menu">
            <li><a onclick="MainPage()">Main</a></li>`;

    countries.forEach(
        (country) =>{
            list +=
                `<li><a onclick="CategoryPage('${country.id}')">${country.name}</a></li>`;
        }
    );

    list += `</ul>`;

    header.innerHTML += list;
}
```